# plot density reflected in scatterplot in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a scatterplot with different point densities in different regions. I hope to use ggplot2 to get a plot like in this figure where the points in high density are in darker blue while in low density lighter blue:

[image]

Maybe this plot is not produced in ggplot2, but I hope to find a function in ggplot2 that achieves the same effect. Thanks!

Comment: This is (almost certainly) not produced with `ggplot2`. It looks very like `base` plotting. Note that a secondary axis in `ggplot2` will be difficult to implement as it is actively not supported. It will also be rather difficult to provide an answer without a reproducible example providing data and what should be plotted (I'm tempted to download the png and use `geom_raster` otherwise).

Comment: @mnel thanks! is there a similar function in ggplot2 that can reflect the point density? All my graphics are now implemented in ggplot2 and I don't wanna switch back to base R...

Comment: just set alpha to something less than 1.